# Is there any environment where "int" would cause struct padding?

Tags: c++, memory, int, alignment

Specifically, this came up in a discussion:

> Memory consuption wise, is there a possibility that using a `struct` of two `int`s take more memory than just two `int`s?

Or, in language terms:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S { int a, b; };

int main() {
    std::cout << (sizeof(S) > sizeof(int) * 2 ? "bigger" : "the same") << std::endl;
}
```

Is there any reasonable<sup>1</sup> (not necessarily common or current) environment where this small program would print `bigger`?

<sup>1</sup>To clarify, what I meant here is systems (and compilers) developed and produced in some meaningful quantity, and specifically not theoretical examples constructed just to prove the point, or one-off prototypes or hobbyist creations.

Comment: I bet this applies to Turbo C++ on a 32 bit OS.

Comment: @Bathsheba Trying this out is worth 15 points! :D

Comment: For Standard diggers, `int` is described as *Plain ints have the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment*, and it has to be big enough to hold `[-INT_MAX, INT_MAX]`, but that obviously doesn't mandate anything.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz -- the language definition indirectly specifies the minimum value of `INT_MAX` (32767) and the maximum value of `INT_MIN` (-32767). `int` has to be at least 16 bits wide.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh yeas I meant that afterwards it could be 17 or 23 bits wide because this can hold `INT_MAX`, which would then potentially cause our `struct` to be padded.

Comment: What if it is aligned but the compiler introduces padding at the end?

Comment: An issue I have with this good question is really the answer hinges on a subjective definition of "reasonable". Therefore I'm afraid the question is really rather opinion-based.

Comment: @Bathsheba My personal opinion here is that if we exclude theoretical made-up examples and hobbyist one-off creations, there's not gonna be even one system like that. I would say that this is a pretty... reasonable definition of reasonable.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: That's good enough for me. Do you think you could chuck that into the question, to keep the closers at bay? For the first time in my life I wish I had a Turbo C++ compiler so I could check my hunch.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I just tested it in Turbo C++ and the sizes are the same.

Comment: It is possible (C++11 or later) to use `alignas` to change the alignment of the `struct`.   For example, `struct alignas(256) foo {int a, b;};` will force introduction of padding, if `int` is less than 128 bits in size. That aside, types are self-aligned on modern architectures, which causes alignment of a `struct` to be determined practically by its largest member, so a `struct` with two `int`s will have no padding. On architectures without barrel-shifters, on which types are not self-aligned padding mighr be introduced into such a struct.  I'm not aware of such an architecture though.

Comment: @Bathsheba Uh what are you talking about? Turbo C++ is 16-bit. It neither knows nor cares about 32-bit OSes. It's obviously not going to change what sizeof returns based on whether or not its 16-bit environment is or is not a virtual machine on a different OS, even if it theoretically had a way to detect that. And why would it require padding on a 32-bit system anyway? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there any reasonable (not necessarily common or current) environment where this small program would print bigger?

Not that I know of. I know that's [not completely reassuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance), but I have reason to believe there is no such environment due to the requirements imposed by the C++ standard.

In a standard-compliant† compiler the following hold:

- (1) arrays cannot have any padding between elements, due to the way they can be accessed with pointers<sup>[ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#8)</sup>;
- (2) standard layout structs may or may not have padding after each member, but *not* at the beginning, because they are layout-compatible with "shorter"-but-equal standard layout structs<sup>[ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#22)</sup>;
- (3) array elements and struct members are properly aligned<sup>[ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align#1)</sup>;

From (1) and (3), it follows that the alignment of a type is less than or equal to its size. Were it greater, an array would need to add padding to have all its elements aligned. For the same reason, the size of a type is always a whole multiple of its alignment.

This means that in a struct as the one given, the second member will always be properly aligned—whatever the size and alignment of ints—if placed right after the first member, i.e., no interstitial padding is required. Under this layout, the size of the struct is also already a multiple of its alignment, so no trailing padding is required either.

**There is no standard-compliant set of (size, alignment) values that we can pick that makes this structure need any form of padding.**

Any such padding would then need a different purpose. However, such a purpose seems elusive. Suppose there is an environment that *needs* this padding for some reason. Whatever the reason for the padding is, it would likely‡ also apply in the case of arrays, but from (1) we know that it cannot.

But suppose such an environment truly exists and we want a C++ compiler for it. It could support this extra required padding in arrays by simply making ints larger that much, i.e. by putting the padding *inside* the ints. This would in turn once more allow the struct to be the same size as two ints and leave us without a reason to add padding.

---

† A compiler—even one otherwise not-standard-compliant—that gets any of these wrong is arguably buggy, so I'll ignore those.

‡ I guess that in an environment where arrays and structures are primitives there might be some underlying distinction that allows us to have unpadded arrays and padded structs, but again, I [don't know of any such thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance) in use.

Comment: From your (3) reference: "An alignment is an implementation-defined integer value representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated."  This is incompatible with your "the alignment of a type is less than or equal to its size" since letting alignment be *smaller* than size allows overlapping objects.

Comment: @Eric it's not incompatible. Overlapping objects do not have to be forbidden here; they can be forbidden by wording elsewhere. Consider the struct given in the question with ints of size and alignment 4 (e.g. clang on my x64 machine). The struct has size 8, alignment 4. There are many many types of where alignment is smaller than its size (any struct with two or more members, or any array with two or more elements)

Comment: If a struct has size 8 and alignment 4, then the "successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated" overlaps the last and first members of successive objects so is not "the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object *can* be allocated."  There is no condition that supports your "the alignment of a type is less than or equal to its size".

Comment: Er, yes, there is. It's right there in that paragraph: "Were it greater, an array would need to add padding to have all its elements aligned". Since arrays cannot have padding, then the alignment cannot be greater. Saying that it cannot be greater is the same as saying that it must be less than or equal.

Comment: If your claim is that the alignment cannot be less than the size, than that is the claim that isn't supported. Note that just because a struct can be placed at addresses 0 and 4 doesn't mean that two objects can be placed at that address *simultaneously*. And since we're checking which claims are supported, the implicit assumption that overlapping objects are not allowed is also unsupported.

Comment: Here are two examples of wording that *explicitly* allows some objects to have overlapping storage: http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#2, http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#3. And this one tacitly acknowledges the existence of partially overlapping objects: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#8.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific example, `struct S { int a, b; };`, I cannot see any reasonable argument for padding. `int` should be naturally aligned already, and if it is, `int *` can and should be the natural representation for pointers, and there is no need for `S *` to be any different. But in general:

A few rare systems have pointers with different representations, where e.g. `int *` is represented as just an integer representing a "word" address, and `char *` is a combination of a word address and a byte offset into that word (where the byte offset is stored in otherwise unneeded high bits of the word address). Dereferencing a `char *` happens in software by loading the word, and then masking and shifting to get the right byte.

On such implementations, it may make sense to ensure all structure types have a minimal alignment, even if it's not necessary for the structure's members, just so that that byte offset mess isn't necessary for pointers to that structure. Meaning it's reasonable that given `struct S { char a, b; };`, `sizeof(S) > 2`. Specifically, I'd expect `sizeof(S) == sizeof(int)`.

I've never personally worked with such implementations, so I don't know if they do indeed produce such padding. But an implementation that does so would be reasonable, and at the very least very close to an existing real-world implementation.

Comment: I have used the (e.g. Cray supercomputers were word-addressable with 64-bit words) and it's a bit more complicated than that. First the hardware is *always* word addressable (only!) so there was no logic in laying out OS data structures etc that tried to fight against that. Second the word address part of a char* was not a "normal" integer - it was limited to a smaller range (e.g only 24 bits on the Cray 1) because that covered the maximum address range of the hardware - but it was stored in a full 64-bit word in memory, with the 3-bit "character within word" pointer stored in the same word.

Comment: @alephzero Thanks, edited my answer to mention the representation. Agreed about OS data structures, but do you happen to remember what happened with user data structures? Although the `struct S { char a, b; };` would probably not be the best choice for that implementation, portable user code might be using it. Do you recall what the implementation did with such types?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not what you asked for, it's not in the spirit of your question (as you probably have standard layout classes in mind), but strictly answering just this part:

> Memory consuption wise, is there a possibility that using a struct of
>   two ints take more memory than just two ints?

the answer is kinda... yes:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    int b;

    virtual ~S() = default;
};
```

<sub>with the pedantic note that C++ doesn't have structs, it has classes. `struct` is a keyword that introduces the declaration/definition of a class.</sub>

Comment: Regarding the pedantic note: funnily enough, yes, there are some structs in the standard http://eel.is/c++draft/class#8 (this is one of the silliest paragraphs in the standard)

Answer (score 2):

It would not be totally implausible that a system which can only access memory in 64-bit chunks might have an option to use a 32-bit "int" size for compatibility with other programs that could get tripped up of uint32_t promotes to a larger type.  On such a system, a struct with an even number of "int" values would likely not have extra padding, but one with an odd number of values might plausibly do so.

From a practical perspective, the only way a struct with two int values would need padding would be if the alignment of a struct was *more than* twice as coarse as that of "int".  That would in turn require either that the alignment of structures be coarser than 64 bits, or that the size of int be smaller than 32 bits.  The latter situation wouldn't be unusual in and of itself, but combining both in a fashion that would make struct alignment more than twice as coarse as int alignment would seem very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically padding is used to provide efficient way of accessing memory area.If adding padding to 2 integer variable would increase the efficient than yes it can have padding.But practically I haven't came across any structure with 2 integer have padding bits.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it? If you can't find an environment that does that, "I haven't stumbled across one yet" isn't really a great argument.

Comment: An obvious candidate (with 32 bit ints and floats) would be `struct S {double d1; int i; double d2; };` Of course the compiler *could* implement this as `struct S {double d1; double d2; int i; };` to eliminate the padding - but you still need padding between the elements of an array of `struct S` to align all the doubles on 64-bit boundaries.

Comment: @alephzero no, the compiler cannot reorder members in standard layout structs.