# Is a struct containing two ints (and only two ints) guaranteed to be twice as large as sizeof(int)?

Tags: c++, memory, struct

Let's say I define a struct:

```
struct intpair
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
    /*Other non-virtual members can go here*/
};
```

Is `sizeof(intpair)` guaranteed by the c++ standard to be `2*sizeof(int)`? If it's not guaranteed, are there any compilers or situations where this wouldn't hold?

Comment: Not guaranteed, but probably will be true on every decent compiler. You could put a `static_assert` to be sure.

Comment: Highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037465/is-there-any-environment-where-int-would-cause-struct-padding#46037465

Comment: @Rakete1111 seems like a duplicate to me

Comment: No, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: This wouldn't hold under a pathological compiler that intentionally seeks to break assumptions that have no support in the standard.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to add padding between `struct` and `class` members.  So, the size of the structure is at least `2 * sizeof(int)`, but may not be exactly equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, it will have that size. But to make sure, add a static_assert:

```
static_assert(sizeof(intpair) == sizeof(int) * 2, "Unexpected struct size");
```

If the assert ever fires, you can scratch your head looking for a solution. Otherwise, you'll be fine. (Why do you need this btw?)

Comment: What about padding?  The compiler is allowed to insert padding between members.  This makes the size >= 2* sizeof(int).